# Java NIO multiple selectors per selectable channel

Tags: java, nio

For Java NIO, can we register multiple selectors for a single selectable channel such that the registered selectors can run select query in parallel with each other on the same channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly. That's why `SelectionKey` exists. It represents a selector/channel pair.

Why you would want to do this is another question.

Comment: Thanks EJP. I want to create a webserver using SocketSelectorChannel/Selector mechanism and compare its performance against the existing webservers. 

I did try running with multiple selectors, but the performance with multiple selectors was coming out to be slower then that of running a single selector. Not sure why that was happening.

Can you point me to some sample code or existing implementation that I can try and mimic.